# Razor always showing default time instead time from database field

Tags: c#, datetime, razor, datetime-format

Returned DateTime from database is OK. But when in razor(in datatable)  it showing as 12:00:00. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VadLP.png)

The method responsible for getting the records from db which is OK since it maps the proper time  from database

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> GetExtendedFanDetails(int FanId, int? ProfileId)
        {
            var profileFan = _fanService.GetFanProfileById(FanId, ProfileId);

            var fanActivities = profileFan.Activities;
            var deliveryActions = profileFan.DeliveryActions;

            var model = new FansTableExtensionViewModel
            {
                FanId = (ProfileId.HasValue) ? profileFan.Id : FanId
            };

            if (fanActivities.Any())
            {
                foreach (var fanactivity in fanActivities)
                {
                    model.FanActivities.Add(new FanActivitiesViewModel
                    {
                        Id = fanactivity.Id,
                        ActivityDate = fanactivity.Created.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"),
                        ActivityName = fanactivity.Activity.Name,
                        ActivityScore = fanactivity.Activity.Score,
                        ActivityType = "FAN Activity",
                        Message = fanactivity.Message
                    });
                };
            }
```

The Razor view part

```
<tbody>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.FanActivities)
                        {
                            <tr data-id="@item.Id">
                                <td>@item.ActivityName</td>
                                <td>@item.ActivityType</td>
                                <td>item.ActivityDate</td>
                                <td>@item.ActivityScore</td>
                                <td data-message="@item.Message">
                                    @item.Message
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
```

What is the problem? I tried all different combinations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date) property of a `DateTime` object always returns the date at `12:00:00`. If you want the exact time, use the `DateTime` object directly.

```
ActivityDate = fanactivity.Created.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: Glad I could help! Consider marking this as the answer to your question so other users might find this as well.